# Mean Stack install on port 80 or or under iis

Tags: node.js, angular, iis, mean-stack, reverse-proxy

I have a Mean stack application that works now on Node Js and port 3000.
I have a Windows Server 2016 and i need to deploy .Net Apps, so i need IIS.
I can't make run both web servers on port 80 but i don't want the users are forced to type the port where running my Mean app.
I tried to work with iisnode, but with no success and i also read about reverse proxy in order to redirect the requests on the port 80 to another port. 
Both solution could be valid, but, before spend other time on the wrong direction i ask what is the best practice in this case.

UPDATE:
a little step forward.
I can now access to the loading page of the app, but the application can't locate my bundle.js (the package created by Webpack).

```
module.exports = webpackMerge.smart(commonConfig, {
    entry: {
        'app': './assets/app/main.aot.ts'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/js/app'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/js/app/',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },
```

My web.config is:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <add name="iisnode" path="start.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
     </handlers>
     <rewrite>
       <rules>
         <rule name="tep">
           <match url="/*" />
           <action type="Rewrite" url="start.js" />
         </rule>
       </rules>
     </rewrite>
     <security>
       <requestFiltering>
         <hiddenSegments>
           <add segment="node_modules" />
         </hiddenSegments>
       </requestFiltering>
     </security> 
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

An extract of start.js file:

```
var app = require('./app');
var debug = require('debug')('node-rest:server');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

And the view (hbs):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/tep">
    <title>Tennis Events Pro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
<tep-app>Loading...</tep-app>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/tep/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I worked around adjusting configuration and paths, with no result...

Thanks

Max

Comment: i suggest using nginx as a forward proxy. more infos here: -
 https://ef.gy/using-nginx-as-a-proxy-server, -https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0

Comment: take a look at this about iisnode: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse proxy with ARR module for IIS will best way to achieve what you want.

1. You need to install [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and [ARR module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) for IIS
2. Enable ARR. On the `Application Request Routing` page, select `Enable proxy`
3. Create Website in IIS Manager
4. Create web.config in this website folder

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><configuration>`

   ```
   <system.webServer>  
       <rewrite>
           <rules>
              <rule name="rewrite to 3000" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url="(.*)" />
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:3000/{R:1}" />
               </rule>
           </rules>
       </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
   ```

   `</configuration>`

After that steps IIS will proxy your requests to port 3000